# Is it possible to in Mysql Replace the Link and make it target blank?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have our database table column named description and in this column have around 1000 row. Each row can contain more than one link. For example:

```
Some description text
<a href="example11.com">Example 11</a>
description text is continue
<a href="example22.com">Example 22</a>
more description text
```

Can i update all links and add target blank. In this example text should changed like:

```
Some description text
<a href="example11.com" target="_blank">Example 11</a>
description text is continue
<a href="example22.com" target="_blank">Example 22</a>
more description text
```

The summary is want to change links and add target blank.

```
<a href="example11.com">Example 11</a>
```

to

```
<a href="example11.com" target="_blank">Example 11</a>
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Mangling HTML in MySQL is not always a good plan. The tools there are exceptionally limited.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to replace a piece of text with another.

For example the following would replace all instances of `<a href` with `<a target="_blank" href`

```
REPLACE(myField, '<a href', '<a target="_blank" href');
```

Using the above on the text you provided in your question would output this:

```
Some description text
<a target="_blank" href="example11.com">Example 11</a>
description text is continue
<a target="_blank" href="example22.com">Example 22</a>
more description text
```

Of course, the `target="_blank"` does not have to follow the `href` and so this is perfectly valid HTML.

It isn't however a perfect solution.  If the anchor tag is not laid out exactly like `<a href` (i.e. a double space, something else instead of `href` directly after the `a`) then this won't work.

To update your data just use a simple `UPDATE` statement using `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE  MyTable
   SET  myField = REPLACE(myField, '<a href', '<a target="_blank" href');
```

[Working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/reiZfW6eVCWsSJ1PgvCH2m/0) showing a simple case of this.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE test 
SET txt = REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '(<a[^>]+href=[^>]+)>(.+<\/a>)', '$1 target="_blank">$2');
```

MySQL 8+ needed.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d56f1ec010d206108f442224a14ea6d